# 'not' css selector in ie9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

According to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp the "not" selector is supported in IE9
However the following doesn't work in ie9:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox"><span>I agree to the terms and conditions</span>
```

CSS:

```
input:not(:checked) + span
{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:red;
}
```

When you check the checkbox, the style is still applied. In other browsers (FF, Chrome) it works as expected.

Is it some sort of bug with IE9?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know if that will help, but try `input:not([checked]) + span`

Comment: IIRC this is an issue with :checked in IE9 rather than :not.

Comment: @Morpheus: Sorry, didn't work ((

Comment: @Morpheus That works on the presence of the `checked` attribute, not whether the user has clicked the checkbox.

Comment: @Mr Lister, I said I don't know if it's going to work :) nice workaround though

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the bug is exactly, but I have got a workaround for you.

With some experimenting I discovered that if you put this line

```css
input:checked + p {}
```

above your CSS, your CSS works fine in IE. So I propose you just put that in and forget about it, unless you want to invest a lot of time in finding out what the extent of the bug is exactly.

```css
input:checked + p {}

input:not(:checked) + span {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"><span>I agree to the terms and conditions</span>
```

To test, you can comment out the first line, and then it stops working in IE.